# Windows server 2008 DNS Server

Tags: domain-name-system

Our security team reported that our DNS server holding our domain, is sometime querying the hostnames from public resolvers while not omitting its own domain name from the query. Like this:
*_ldap._tcp.Defauldt-First-Site-Name._sites.DC-Exchange.MY-DOMAIN.COM*

Thus, it has been raised a security issue for us, as our domain name is being revealed in public queries.
The DNS Server is on Windows Server 2008 and the domain controller is the one my MS-Exchange server queries DNS records from.

I wonder

1) How did they discover / detect this issue?

2) How this can be resolved.

Comment: What DNS servers are configured in the DNS settings of the TCP/IPv4 of the NIC on the server?

Comment: the only DNS server IP address configured on NIC is 127.0.0.1